# SQL query base on three relation with restriction

Tags: sql, oracle

- Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PostCode)
- Salesman (SalesmanNo, empName)
- Account (AccountNo, SalesmanNo, CustomerID, AccountType)

How do I achieve this:

Get the name of customer purchase from **both** Sean and Jean, i believe with the below nested query statement I get the customerID who purchase from both salesman.

result like

```
     CustomerID 
1.   043
2.   100
3.   203
4.   011
5.   045
6.   008
```

```
((select distinct A.CustomerID as CustomerID from account A
Inner Join Salesman S on A.SalesmanNo = S.SalesmanNo
where S.empname = 'Sean')
Intersect
(select distinct A.CustomerID as CustomerID from account A
Inner Join Salesman S on A.SalesmanNo = S.SalesmanNo
where S.empname = 'Jean'))
```

but when i add

```
Select C.Firstname, C.LastName from Customer C
Inner Join
((select distinct A.CustomerID as CustomerID from account A
Inner Join Salesman S on A.SalesmanNo = S.SalesmanNo
where S.empname = 'Sean')
Intersect
(select distinct A.CustomerID as CustomerID from account A
Inner Join Salesman S on A.SalesmanNo = S.SalesmanNo
where S.empname = 'Jean')) 
As CID on C.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
```

I get error ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
and the CID is flag so when i placed my cursor the CID (Syntax Error. Partially recognized rules(railroad diagram):

---

Please help

Comment: Too many brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that you will get similar results for JOIN and IN, it is better to use IN predicate for filtering and JOIN part to enrich the data with more data. Because over the years from IN you'll expect nothing more than filtering and will not need to try to remember or understand the purpose of any particular JOIN.

Your error is cause by `AS` before table alias `CID`, because Oracle [does not expect `AS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126863) before it.
The query is:

```
Select C.Firstname, C.LastName
from Customer C
where CustomerID in (
 select a.CustomerID
 from Account A
 where a.SalesmanNo in (select s.SalesmanNo from Salesman s where S.empname in ('Sean','Jean'))
 group by a.CustomerID
 having count(distinct a.SalesmanNo) = 2
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. another question, what would be the proper statement for table alias the nested result? could you just give me an example please.

Comment: @derrick You've already used it: <tablename | subquery> <alias>. Without AS between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select A.CustomerID as CustomerID 
from account A Inner Join Salesman S on A.SalesmanNo = S.SalesmanNo
where S.empname in ('Sean','Jean') group by A.CustomerID
having count(distinct S.empname)=2
```